# jQuery UI Autocomplete IE Cursor Position Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have just implemented the excellent jQuery UI autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

There is a strange bug in IE 8 (and maybe other versions).

When you select an item from the box of suggestions in IE 8 the cursor moves to the begining of the textbox before the suggested word which has just been inserted.

Firefox put the cursor after the inserted word.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code into the select event that is passed to the autocomplte function.

So if you have:

```
jQuery('someval').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

Change it to be:

```
jQuery('some_val').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,

    select : function(event, ui){
            if(document.selection) { 
                this.focus(); 
                var oSel = document.selection.createRange(); 
                oSel.moveStart('character',this.value.length); 
                oSel.moveEnd('character',0); 
                oSel.select(); 
            } 
        }
})
```

See more: 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-autocomplete-multiple-demo-caret-position-in-ie
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Aaron, I didnt find that answer in any of my googling. However I cant see how to implement this fix. 

I have searched for the non-minified versions of jquery ui core, autocomplete and the jquery library itself and cant find the line 
'this.value = terms.join(", ");' anywhere. 


I dont know if this fix relates to an old version though the post is less than a month old. 

Very strange. 

Any other ideas?

Regards

Steve

Comment: Oh that was specific to the multiple version of the autocomplete. It was supposed to be added in the select event of the .autocomplete code. I'll edit what I found into the post.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, working beautifully. Just knew even after spending a couple of days updating our platform to support autocomplete the first thing the client would do is moan about this glitch. 

Cheers!

Comment: No problem, it always surprises me what clients will sometimes complain about first. Sometimes they will ignore what looks like a giant pink elephant to us, to point out a speck of dirt. **shrug**

Answer (score 1):

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6858
This one helped me a lot!