# Can't scroll by click, autocomplete, IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 $("#inputFindLocation").autocomplete({

        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON(BASE_URL + "/Extract/FindLocation", {
                searchForString: $("#inputFindLocation").val()
            }, response);
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item && ui.item.XCoordinate && ui.item.YCoordinate) {
                panTo(ui.item.XCoordinate, ui.item.YCoordinate);
                $("#dialogFindLocation").dialog("close");
                $("#inputFindLocation").val("");
            }
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {

            $(this).autocomplete("widget").css("z-index", 110);

           return false;
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.PlaceName + " (" + item.County + ", " + item.Municipality + ")</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);

    };
```

This works fine In Firefox. However, In Internet Explorer I can't navigate/scroll down the list by clicking on the down arrow icon In the scroll bar. The first Item are always selected. If I hold in the down arrow icon, It works.

If I drag down to the end of the list, and then click on the up arrow, It scrolls up to the beginning of the list, instead of one item at time.

It seems like the first item are "selected" by default, and that's why this error occur. But how can I solve this?

Here Is a similar question: [jQuery UI Autocomplete IE Cursor Position Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036998/jquery-ui-autocomplete-ie-cursor-position-bug)

Comment: Can you provide MCVE? How do you debug it? Which specific method doesn't work on IE? `panTo(ui.item.XCoordinate, ui.item.YCoordinate)`?

Comment: @A.Wolff: What do u mean with MCVE? I do not debug It. I think It Is the autocomplete method that does not work? I have described my problem above, and I don't know what causing It.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Just provide jsFiddle replicating your issue. It could be a bug in autocomplete but i guess no. So which method is suppose to do the scroll? A custom one you are using or a native one relative to jQuery autocomplete plugin??? `I do not debug It` Wait, that's the first thing you should do. Error in console? Etc...

Comment: @A.Wolff: I get no error in the console or what so ever.